Wrong Time deduction from ToQueryString EF MySql
What is the result of ToQueryString when we have time deduction?
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromHours(10); var query = context.table1.Where(x => x.Status == 3 && x.CreatedAt < DateTime.Now - t); var sql = query.ToQueryString();
The result of ToQueryString is not correct IMO. Then what is the correct value?
The output of ToQueryString is
SET @__t_0 = TIME '10:00:00.000000';
SELECT t.Id, t.CreatedAt, t.Status
FROM table1 AS t
WHERE (t.Status = 3) AND (t.CreatedAt < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 
@__t_0));

which makes the time deduction wrong. actually the result of this query is similar to if we wouldn't have 'AND (t.CreatedAt<(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - @__t_0))' at all.
But if I run the C# code, it will return a result in which the time deduction is considered and this is telling me that the code that is executed on MySql at the end is different than the result of ToQueryString.

Post the query and explain the actual problem in the question itself. Are you sure there is a problem in the first place? Do the actual and expected queries result in different execution plans? If they do, are you sure the one you expected is better?

Yes, the expected and actual one having different result at the end. I think the expected one is correct because is the one that is getting executed at the end. And seeing the final query was my purpose of using ToQueryString in first place.

Looks like a bug in the provider it shoud have used DATEADD or DATESUB, you can file it at https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Try using DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10)

already filed an issue.
https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1926

The issue text is misleading. There will be some confusion until people understand what you ask, and they'll ask the same things we did.  The problem has nothing to do with ToQueryString, it's about  how subtracting 10 hours gets translated to - instead of DATESUB. Even your expected query is wrong according to the docs

Tried DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10) and works well.
